# Looping a login prompt in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I wasn't quite sure how to title this question, open to edits.

This is what I am currently using for the login system.

```
if (accountq === "Add", " Add", " Add "){
    var usrin = prompt("Username: ")
}

if (usrin === usrname){
    var passin = prompt("Ah, hello. Password?: ")
}

do {  
    if (passin !== pswdb){
       var passin = prompt("Sorry, that pass does not match.")
    }
}
while(passin === pswdb){
    console.log("Username and password have been authenticated")
    var addname = prompt("Name: ")
    console.log(
        "Okay, noted that. Please give us the direct download link"
    )

    var directlink = prompt("Direct Link: ")
    console.log("Thank you! Will add that.")
} 

while(passin !== pswdb){
    wrongpass()
} //this was my attempt to trigger the prompt again, but it failed.
```

I am trying to prompt for a password until a correct password is entered, and then go on to the rest of the code, I've tried while, but with no luck, can someone point me in the correct direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this? It's simple, small, and seems similar to your attempted solution:

```
var prompt = require('prompt-sync')()

var expectedPass = 'myPassword'

while (true) {
  var username = prompt('Username:')
  var password = prompt('Password:')
  if (password == expectedPass) break
  else console.log('Sorry, that pass does not match.')
}

console.log('Match!')

/* ... rest of code ... */
```

Please note the following security and performance bits:

1. `prompt-sync` is a *blocking* prompt, which means any other asyncronous activities will be blocked until the user responds. This won't be a prompt unless you're doing other things in this process.
2. Security-wise, a user could simply open the file and read the password to get around this security prompt.

If either of these are problems, then you may be looking for a different solution. Let me know if that's the case!

Comment: I am using a database, but yes, this works perfectly! Thank you.